# How to make collapse button inside div properly in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am tring to make a collapse button for my quote container but when I click it, on the first click, nothing happens but when I click again, the whole div disappears? I think I am following correctly the sample here? [getbootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#collapsehide/)

Also in my fiddle my collapse button the minus(-) is not functioning. But in my google chrome browser it is ok? Is it also possible that when I collapse, when it's collapse I can change to another fontawesome icon? the minus becomes plus when collapse/hidden?
this is my code and js fiddle:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/e5dr6m7z/)

HTML

```
<div class="quote-box" id="collapse-quote">
  <div class="text">
    asdasd
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">

    <button class="button" id="twitter-button"><a title="Tweet this quote!" target="_blank"> tweet
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </a></button>

    <button class="button" id="facebook-button"><a title="Share this quote!" target="_blank">share
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </a></button>

    <button class="button" id="close-open" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-quote" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-quote">
      <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

scss

```
.quote-box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10% auto auto auto;
  /* center the box */
}

.quote-box .buttons {
  top: 0;
  /* align to top */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* out of the document flow and you can move*/
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* sample: uncomment if you want to align on right 
#twitter-button{
  float: right;
} 
*/

#close-open {
  /* float the collapse button to the right */
  float: right;
}

.fa-minus {
  color: #11A5D6;
  /* color for the button */
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I been fixing for a button for hours.

Comment: Why do you have jQuery twice? Check console for any errors/conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. All I did was remove your `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` reference and changed your `bootstrap.min.js` to use `https`.

You have other issues too, check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77ew2bce/).

css

```
.quote-box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10% auto auto auto; /* center the box */
}
```

html, you were missing the collapse class on the div, and also if you collapse all the buttons how are you supposed to get back to them?

```
<div class="quote-box">
    <div class="text collapse" id="collapse-quote">
       asdasd
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">

        <button class="button" id="twitter-button"><a   title="Tweet this quote!" target="_blank"> tweet
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a></button>

        <button class="button" id="facebook-button"><a   title="Share this quote!" target="_blank">share
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a></button>

        <button class="button" id="close-open" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-quote" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-quote">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I followed your instruct but still doesnt work for me,on the first click nothing happens and on the 2nd click, all disappears, also when I put collapse on quote-box container the container shows no result or is it collapsed?

Comment: cause  when I put collapse, nothing shows to me, and I followed your instructions but what is to hide the contents but the buttons remain. Is that possible and also when I click hide the botton changes icon?

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio Look at the code I posted, it only hides the content and the buttons remain. Yes, you can use [jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to change button icons.